# Gulp - recompile a bumped version for tagging

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp

Regarding an [issue I am having with gulp-tag-version](https://github.com/ikari-pl/gulp-tag-version/issues/4), the README there suggests:

```
function inc(importance) {
    // get all the files to bump version in
    return gulp.src(['./package.json', './bower.json']) 
        // bump the version number in those files
        .pipe(bump({type: importance}))
        // save it back to filesystem
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))

        /*  Recompile the Javascript here */

        // commit the changed version number
        .pipe(git.commit('bumps package version')) 
        // read only one file to get the version number
        .pipe(filter('package.json'))
        // **tag it in the repository**
        .pipe(tag_version()) 
}

gulp.task('patch', function() { return inc('patch'); })
gulp.task('feature', function() { return inc('minor'); })
gulp.task('release', function() { return inc('major'); })
```

I would like to recompile some Javascript between the version being bumped and git tagging it. I have a task for that, `js`, but it is not clear how one can call the `js` task (or otherwise re-order the bump/tag tasks) to accomplish this common and desirable outcome (i.e. having the version in the headers of your compiled code).

It is also worth noting that if one had three tasks `bump`, `compile` and `tag`, the `bump` of the `package.json` appears to be cached and not re-read by a separate `tag` task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple way to get this working is to get 3 new separate tasks that depend on each others:

- `tag` depends on `commit`, since the tag will be applied to the last commit we have to do that before
- `commit` depends on `js`, because we should re-build your files with the bumped version
- `js` depends on `bump`, bump the version of your manifest files before doing anything
- `bump` has no dependencies.

Problem with this is that you will have to change your `js` to add the `bump` dependency, and I'm sure that you don't want to bump each time you recompile or one of your `watch` is triggered.

So you could use something like **[run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence)** to bypass that.

Also one thing I like to reduce the number of gulp tasks is to use arguments, but you can stick with the `inc` function if you want, that's a detail (here `--major`, `--minor`, or `--patch`).

So you could do something like this (from top to down in the execution order):

```
gulp.task('uprev', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./package.json', './bower.json'])
    .pipe(bump({ type: process.argv[3] ? process.argv[3].substr(2) : 'patch' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('rebuild', function (cb) {
  runSequence('uprev', 'js', cb); //uprev will here be executed before js
});

gulp.task('commit', ['rebuild'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['./package.json', './bower.json', 'dist/**/*'])
      .pipe(git.add())
      .pipe(git.commit('bump version'));
});

gulp.task('bump', ['commit'], function () {
  return gulp.src('package.json')
    .pipe(tagVersion());
});
```

For your commit, you may want to add both of your manifest and the compiled files, I've added all the content of a random `dist` folder for demo.

I've intentionally cut the `bump` and `commit` tasks so you don't have to use *gulp-filter*, which seems to me pretty useless for this little kind of thing, but it's as you want of course.

One last thing (promise), you could avoid to use *gulp-tag-version* by using a simple *node fs call* combined with *gulp-git* you already have:

```
gulp.task('bump', ['commit'], function (cb) {
  fs.readFile('./package.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    var version = JSON.parse(data.toString()).version;
    git.tag(version, 'Version message', function (err) {
      cb(err);
    });
});
```